# CRM 2016 Upgrade Service - Case - Environments

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

We have recently made our last push to CRM 2016 (on-premise). Our Support team has suddenly noticed that for any given Case under [General > Contract and Product Information] it has started to list ALL Active Environments. In past, it used to only show a linked Environment to the given Case.

[image]

Dropdown image:
[image]

Similarly, for each given Case under [Invoice Products] its listing all Products.

Comment: your question is very unclear, verify if view is changed in subgrid?

Comment: Thanks Arun. No changes are made, its as vanilla as it gets. In the subgrid it used to (in CRM 2015) list only the related environments to the Case in view.

Comment: can you add some screenshot to explain? all are oob or custom entities?

Comment: Certainly ! (adding above).. So as soon as we add a Case.. all Active Environments ever created show up (206 of them).. same goes for the Invoice Products.. Keeping in mind this Form is the 'Information' which was carried over from CRM 2015 during upgrades. The new Form doesn't have this subgrid at all.

Comment: check the subgrid properties - in Data source section, do you have the option selected - 'only related records' ?

Comment: Arun, you suggestion was spot on.. however there is an issue when i select 'only related records' the 'environments' entity disappears from the drop down.. attaching at snap above..

Comment: that means relationship is missing between case & environment.. you have to investigate. this is going broad.

Comment: also see if you fail to move some JS webresource which is filtering the resultset using fetchxml or something (in case relationship is not available)

Comment: I can see a 1:N Account relationship: am_account_am_environment with primary Account and related Environment of type Parental. Similarly N:1 exists on Environment side.

Comment: then definitely you are showing filtered results in subgrid using fetchxml filter, as the relationship is between Account (Customer of Case) & Environment, not between Case & Environment right?

Comment: That is correct.. there is no Case:Environment relationship..

Answer (score 0):

Here are the troubleshooting steps:

1. Make sure relationship exists between the entities & its searchable
2. In Subgrid properties, verify the Data source section for the option - 'Only Related Records' selected in `Records`

[image]

3. If there is no direct relationship between entities, some JS webresource might be used to filter records using fetchxml - this may be broken